# Powershell .csv merge with column remove

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

Using the code below I am able to merge several .csv files in  5 seconds.

```
    $getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem "C:\my\dir\*.csv" | foreach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines =  $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
    $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
           $true  {$lines}
           $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}

    }

    $getFirstLine = $false
    Add-Content "C:\my\dir\output_code2.csv" $linesToWrite
    }
```

I would like to take this one step further, preferable using piping to remove several of the columns using a command like:

```
select DateAndTime,DG1_KW,DG2_KW,WT_KW,HTR1_KW,POSS_Load_KW,INV1_KW,INV2_SOC|Export-csv output_test.csv -Notypeinformation
```

that being the variables in the header of each file.

How would I modify this code to make this work?  The idea here is that I am going to be working with hundreds up to thousands of files.

I have other code which can do this but it is no where near as fast.

for instance using 10 .csv files that are 450kb each.  the code below takes 20 seconds to process and spits out a .csv file in 20 seconds removing 48 of the 56 columns leaving the variables I need.  If I remove part of the code that trims the columns it still takes 12+ seconds.

```
# Directory containing csv files, include *.*
$directory = "C:\my\dir\*.*";
# Get the csv files
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter *.csv;
#$content = $null;
$content = @();

# Process each file
foreach($csv in $csvFiles)
{
    $content += Import-Csv $csv;
}

# Write a datetime stamped csv file
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss";
$content |Export-Csv -Path "C:\my\dir\output_code2_$datetime.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

The code I would like to modify runs those same 10 files in 5 seconds but does not remove the 48 columns.

Any Ideas guys?

Comment: Your fast code works so fast because it does not treat the file as a CSV it just treats it as text and does not have to create objects for each record, it's just an array of strings. If your files all have the same columns you could use a regex replace to remove extra columns, but they would all have to be formatted the same way.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician  could you give an example of what this code would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want an example... Let's say your CSVs always look like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data10
dataA,dataB,dataC,dataD,dataE,dataF,dataG,dataH,dataI,dataJ
```

Now let's say you only want Col1, Col2, Col6, Col9, and Col10. You could do a RegEx replace something like:

```
$Files = get-childItem "C:\my\dir\*.csv" | Select -Expand FullName
ForEach($File in $Files){
    If($SkipFirst){
        Get-Content $File | Select -Skip 1 | ForEach{$_ -replace "^((?:.*?\,){2})(?:.*\,){3}(.*?\,)(?:(?:.*?\,){2})(.*?,.*?)$", '$1$2$3'} | Add-Content "C:\my\dir\output_code2.csv"
    }Else{
        Get-Content $File | ForEach{$_ -replace "^((?:.*?\,){2})(?:.*\,){3}(.*?\,)(?:(?:.*?\,){2})(.*?,.*?)$", '$1$2$3'} | Add-Content "C:\my\dir\output_code2.csv"
    }
}
```

That would extract just the columns that I noted above. See https://regex101.com/r/jY4oO6/1 for detailed breakdown of RegEx string. Effective output would be (skipping first line if so dictated):

```
Col1,Col2,Col6,Col9,Col10
data1,data2,data6,data9,data10
dataA,dataB,dataF,dataI,dataJ
```